# How to pass the input value to the code behind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, vbscript

I was using asp textbox, but somehow it can not be focused in apple devices, so I tried input tag in html, it worked. But now I need to pass the value to the back(vb script) I tried request.form/request.querystring, none of them worked.

This is the code passed value to vb, but can not be focused:
ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Height="100"        Font－Size="50"/>
<a href="javascript: PressEnterViaNextButton();"/>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("txtUserID").focus();
```

VB:

```
Private Sub txtUserID_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtUserID.TextChanged
        Session("UserID") = txtUserID.Text
    End Sub
```

This is the code can be focused but, I don't know how to pass the value.

ASPX:

```
<input runat="server" id="txtUserID" name="txtUserID1" type="text" class="input"  onchange="getValue(this.value)" value="1"/>
                    <a href="javascript: PressEnterViaNextButton();"/>
```

VB:

```
Dim userid As String = Request.Form("txtUserID")
```

Comment: `txtUserID.Text` if I understand you correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a HTML input and want the value of the textbox on the server side code then you would be reading the value of the textbox back from the querystring collection in Page_Load event.

```
HTML CODE
'
<input type="text" id="txtUserid" name="txtUserid" value="1" />
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
<p>
  My User Id: <%=Session("MyUserId")%>
</p>


SERVER-SIDE CODE
'
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
'
' Submit button was pressed
If Request("btnSubmit") = "Submit" Then
    Session("MyUserId") = Request("txtUserId")
End If
'
End Sub
```

On pressing the submit button, the <p> tag would now contain the data from the textbox.

Comment: Just tried it, did't work.. And my goal is I need the text box focused on the IOS..

Comment: Sorry the TYPE for button should have been SUBMIT not BUTTON, I corrected the code.

Comment: Ok, just tried another way of your code. it is passing the value now. Thank you.

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if it is right, 
if not then fair enough , thanks

Comment: Thank You Call me Newbie